# Why am I receiving a PDO query error?

Tags: php, pdo

Apologies in advance because I'm really unsure how to ask this question so if you need to know anything then please comment rather than downvote and I will edit.

I have teaser links on my main page which when clicked open up a window with the full article.  I'm currently converting my MySQL code over to PDO and have gotten a little stuck.

In MySQL I used to be doing the following (Here, $foo_query is the query from the first page):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT id, postdate, title, body FROM FooBarTable WHERE id = $id";
if ($foo_query = mysql_query($sql)) {
    $r     = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo_query);
    $title = $r["title"];
    $body  = $r["body"];
}
```

Which is simple to understand to me.  I've been trying to convert this using what I know, and it turns out I don't know very much.  So far I have the following:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, postdate, title, body FROM FooBarTable WHERE id = :id OR id = $id");
$sql->bindParam(':id', $_REQUEST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
if ($foo_query = $DBH->query($sql)) {
    $r->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $r     = $foo_query->fetch();
    $title = $r["title"];
    $body  = $r["body"];
}
$sql->execute();
```

This brings up an error of 'PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string'.  This is for the 'if' line.

Have I even written any of that PDO correctly?  What would I need to do from here?  A friend has recently taught me MySQL, but he doesn't know PDO at all which means I can't ask his advice (not all that helpful...)

Comment: You need to run query on `$sql`, not directly on the database handle.

Comment: Why do you bother to use prepared statements if you're just gonna inject user input directly into them?  That `OR id = $id` shouldn't be in there...if you want it in there for some reason, make it a param and bind it like you did the other `:id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct way, with comments:

```
try {
    //Connect to the database, store the connection as a PDO object into $db.
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "password");

    //PDO will throw PDOExceptions on errors, this means you don't need to explicitely check for errors.
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //PDO will not emulate prepared statements. This solves some edge cases, and relives work from the PDO object.
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    //Prepare the statement.
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT id, postdate, title, body FROM FooBarTable WHERE id = :id");
    //Bind the Value, binding parameters should be used when the same query is run repeatedly with different parameters.
    $statement->bindValue(":id", $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    //Execute the query
    $statement->execute();

    //Fetch all of the results.
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //$result now contains the entire resultset from the query.
}
//In the case an error occurs, a PDOException will be thrown. We catch it here.
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why it's all contained within a try/catch loop?  Should it always be contained there or is there a specific reason you've done this?  Note that this actually returned a blank query after echoing $result["title"] (for example).

Comment: Am I also right in thinking that I shouldn't set ERRMODE_EXCEPTION when my site goes live?

Comment: @tomdot: You are wrong. ERRMODE_EXCEPTION should always be left on. That way, PDO throws PDOExceptions, which are catchable (with the `try/catch` block), which allows you to handle errors in any way you want. Read more about [Exceptions and try/catch here](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Very helpful and very interesting.  Still, it's returning a blank query unless I turn that fetchAll into a while loop and name some variables.

Comment: Answer accepted over @JvdBerg because of the explanation of what's what and the extra knowledge...but Berg's answer was cool too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead of [`PDO::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

```
$foo_query = $sql->execute();
```

You may also bind all your params at once when calling `execute`:

```
$foo_query = $sql->execute(array(
    ':id' => $id
));
```

Comment: This won't work, you only can use parameters of type `PDO::PARAM_STR` in the execute.

Comment: MySQL will auto convert to INT.

Comment: From the manual: `An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: I know, I mean it works on MySQL anyway, since it will autoconvert even if you do `WHERE intcol = '5'` .

Comment: @JvdBerg: True, but MySQL will understand the number even if it is passed as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it to:

```
$sql->execute();
if($r = $sql->fetch()) {
    $title = $r["title"];
    $body = $r["body"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, postdate, title, body 
  FROM FooBarTable WHERE id = :id OR id = $id");
$sql->bindParam (':id', $_REQUEST['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $title = $row["title"];
  $body = $row["body"];
}
```